# How to convert file encoding type to UTF-8 in Golang?

Tags: go

I have to write a code to check the subtitle file encoding, and if it isn't UTF-8, change the encoding to it. To get the file to encode type, I write this function in Golang:

```
func CheckEncoding(filePath string) (encode string, err error) {

    content, _ := os.ReadFile(filePath)
    contentType := http.DetectContentType(content)
    encode = strings.Split((strings.Split(contentType, " "))[1], "=")[1]

    return encode, err
}
```

With this function, I get the subtitle encoding. After that, I want to check if the encoding is not equal to "utf-8" convert to this and save the subtitle with this new encoding(utf-8) in the new file, but I don't know how can I do it.

I have used the [iconv](https://github.com/djimenez/iconv-go) package, but I cannot save the output in the new file .
Another thing that I read was  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518432/how-to-convert-from-an-encoding-to-utf-8-in-go) answer, but it was too complex and didn't help me.All other answers are about converting a string encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check if the encoding is utf-8

```
e, _, _ := charset.DetermineEncoding(content, "")
```

Then convert and save to the new file

```
// Convert the string to UTF-8
utf8Content, err := e.NewDecoder().Bytes(content)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Save the file as UTF-8
err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, utf8Content, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I didn't test this code yet. Just draft to get the idea.